# Continuity of Derivative of Analytic Function on Disc Boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Suppose we have an analytic function $f(z)$ defined on a closed disc $D$ in the complex plane, so that it is complex-differentiable inside and on the boundary of $D$ (see edit below). I know that this implies that $f$ is infinitely differentiable on the interior of $D$, which can be proven using Cauchy's integral.

However, this approach fails when $z$ is on the boundary of $D$, so my question is does $f'$ necessarily have to be continuous or even
bounded on the boundary of $D$? Are there counterexamples?

I've already found a simple counterexample showing that $f'$ doesn't need to be differentiable:
\begin{equation}
f(z) = z^\frac{3}{2}, \; z \in \bar B_1(1)
\end{equation}
However, its derivative is still continuous.

**EDIT:** Sorry for the confusion, when I said that it it complex differentiable on the boundary of the disc, I meant that we use the usual definition of differentiability, but when we take the limit of the difference quotient we only consider open neighborhoods in the *relative* topology of the disc (so it might not be able to analytically extend to an open neighborhood in $\mathbb{C}$). This question is just about whether or not that derivative is necessarily continuous.

Comment: Your function is not even a well defined function. It certainly not a complex differentiable function inside the disk.

Comment: Why not? Maybe I should clarify: it's defined on the disc centered at z=1 and with a radius of 1, so it can be made single valued, and it is easy to check that it's differentiable at z=0.

Comment: @EthanK: it is not possible to define as an analytic function $z^{\frac32}$ on a neighbourhood of $0$. To define it, you need a branch of the logarithm, which is defined only on simply connected sets in $\Bbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Comment: A counterexample to the differentiability is still easy: consider $f(z)=\ln(1-z)(1-z)^2$ on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}-\{1\}$ extended on the whole disc with $f(1)=0$. It is easy to see that $f(e^{ix})$ is not twice differentiable, and so $f'$ is not differentiable in your sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is phrased poorly as complex differentiability, means differentiability when $z$ approaches from all directions towards a point and in your example, $z^{3/2}$ is not continuously defined at $0$ on a full disc around zero - sure, one can define it continuously on a slit disc (so in particular from the inside of your disc $B_1(1)$) and then $f'(z) \to 0, z \to 0, z \in B_1(1)$ but that doesn't make $f$ differentiable (in the complex sense) at $0$ only $f$ differentiable in the real sense on $\partial B_1(1)$ which is a real manifold of dimension $1$ (a circle, or locally an arc)

There are easy examples of functions for which $f^{(k)}, k \le N$ converges from inside the disc at any point on the boundary but the boundary value $f$ (which is then $N$ real differentiable) doesn't extend analytically at any point (just take $\sum \frac{z^{2^n}}{n^2}$ on the unit disc and integrate it $N$ times, so the result $f_N$ has the unit disc as a natural boundary but it's derivatives up to order $N$ converge to the boundary and they are continuos) and with more care one can arrange so $f$ is infinitely differentiable ($C^{\infty}$) on the boundary, or even stronger all the derivatives converge from inside the circle at any boundary point, but the circle is still a natural boundary.

Summarizing - the convergence of the derivative to a boundary point from inside the circle doesn't tell you anything about the existence of the derivative there in the complex sense (which again generally means that $f$ extends analytically on a small ball etc )

Comment: How easy is it to see that complex differentiability at a single point implies complex differentiability on some open containing that point...?

Comment: @paul you can have complex differentiability at an isolated point only eg $z\bar z$ at zero, but the point here is that complex differentiability requires the function to be defined in a neighborhood and the limit defining it exists when approaching from all directions and that's where the $z^{3/2}$ argument fails as there is no way to define that to be continuos in a neighborhood of zero (and as in the real case differentiability implies continuity at a given point) -

Comment: thanks. I guess all my intuition is for holomorphic/complex-diff on an _open_ (non-empty)...

Comment: @paul I agree - that is the usual meaning (the rest are generally curiosities), while boundary behaviour is a very interesting and complicated topic as I tried to convey above

Comment: Yes, I edited my question to make what I was asking more clear hopefully. Your example is interesting, and the continuity of the derivatives does imply that it's differentiable in my sense, but I really want to know if there exists a function that's differentiable in my sense but has a discontinuous derivative.